# Ethernet internet cuts out - toggling it off and on fixes it 18.04

Tags: internet, ethernet, realtek

Ubuntu 18.04

Realtek Ethernet Controller

lspci output [here](https://pastebin.com/JQubCwmx)

My internet connection via Ethernet will occasionally (few times a week, using it about 10 hours a week) just quit working. There is no indicator that there is an issue (like in the system tray) other than nothing will load.

Toggling the Ethernet connection off and back on, fixes the issue.

Not sure what other data or logs to provide. Please let me know what would help and I'll provide it. Thanks!

EDIT:

output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 06
       serial: fc:aa:14:e0:d8:71
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.2.202 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:b000(size=256) memory:fe500000-fe500fff memory:d0900000-d0903fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 03
       serial: ec:08:6b:d9:ea:cf
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:fe400000-fe407fff memory:fe200000-fe3fffff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: virbr0
       serial: 52:54:00:25:8e:9f
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.122.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:25:8e:9f
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

output of `dkms status`

```
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.3.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.3.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
hid-xpadneo, 0.6.0, 5.3.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
hid-xpadneo, 0.6.0, 5.3.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `dkms status`.

Comment: see edit. This is just from right now and not immediately after this issue has occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cables

Your `sudo lshw -C network` indicates two things...

```
size: 100Mbit/s
capacity: 1Gbit/s
```

Your ethernet has 1Gb capability, but is only running at 100Mb... one tenth speed. This usually means a cable problem. Are you running with cat 5e or cat 6 cables? I could also mean that there are gigabit switches or routers that aren't working properly. Check your cables. Check your network hardware.

```
driver=r8169
```

The r8169 driver is kind of flakey. Replace it with the r8168 driver, like so...

`sudo apt-get update` # update the software database

`sudo apt-get install dkms r8168-dkms` # install the new driver

`reboot` # reboot the computer

**Update #1:**

There's a TP-Link powerline adapter pair that connects the computer to the router/modem.

Install the TP-Link Powerline Utility from the install CD, or download a fresh copy from https://www.tp-link.com.

Download the latest firmware for your PL adapters from https://www.tp-link.com.

Upgrade your TP-Link PL adapter firmware using instructions from https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/405/

**Update #2:**

No US firmware updates are available for the TP-Link powerline set.

**Update #3:**

Temporarily removed the PowerLine adapters and ran an ethernet cable directly from the computer to the router. It seems to be working fine now. Suspect PL problem.

Comment: I use a tp-link powerline adapter, I will check out the cable and model to see what speed they're rated for.y internet is only 30mbps anyway so I never really paid attention to device throughput. I'm aware of the issues of that driver (with arch) so that makes sense. I'll try to install that driver as well.

Comment: @BingBong Check the TP-Link PL adapter. Are there any yellow/red lights on, on the adapter? If you look at the Utility, can you see what connection speed between the two adapters is?

Comment: No just a green light. I wasn't aware that there was a tp-link PL utility program for linux. I'll have to check that out

Comment: @BingBong I think it's a Windows-only utility.

Comment: Back at my pc. They say right on the PL adapters that they're 200Mbps. They're using Cat 5 cables. I shall try that new driver and see if over time I no longer have that problem. Is there a way i can set a reminder here on stackexchange/askubuntu, to ping me a notification? Reddit has !remindme xx [units of time] or something like that.

Comment: @BingBong The 200Mb/sec PL adapters probably don't have gigabit ethernet ports on them, but you'll have to check the specs for them. If they ARE gigabit ethernet ports, then you'll need to use cat 5e or cat 6 cables to get the proper speed. You may wish to consider upgrading to a newer/faster PL adapter. Did you try the Windows PL Utility? I'm not aware of a timer here.

Comment: New driver did not help. Any error log I can generate for you to assist in troubleshooting?

Comment: @BingBong Please describe your network from the back of the computer, all the way through the PL, to wherever it goes after that. Is your computer a laptop or a desktop?

Comment: Computer to PL adapter, 2nd PL adapter in next room to the router. Router to the modem. Computer is a desktop. I can try to look at all of the ethernet cables used later, and report back (supposed to be working right now)

Comment: I hit enter too soon and couldn't go back to edit it all in time (5 min restriction). -- router is an Asus RT-N56U -- modem is Arris Surfboard SB6183 (mine not ISPs) -- ethernet cables from computer to PL adapter, and from PL adapter to router are both CAT 5. -- Ethernet cable from router to modem is CAT 5e provided by Spectrum (ISP).

Comment: @BingBong Please see Update #1 in my answer.

Comment: Nice, thank you and I'll try to do that tonight. And after some hours of use I'll report back whether that solved it. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Can't find the US version of the firmware. I asked their customer support and they couldn't find a US version either and recommended that I don't use the EU version. https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/TL-PA2010/ so I think I've reached the end of the road. Next step for this issue might be buying a new PL adapter.

Comment: @BingBong As much as it might be difficult to do... I believe that you said you had a desktop machine, yes? Temporarily move the desktop machine next to the router/modem (or near the 2nd PL adapter, and then just connect to that ethernet cable) and plug it in directly, thereby eliminating the PL stuff... and that should tell you for sure if they're the problem. Report back.

Comment: Thanks. I've got a long ethernet cord so I'll run that to it. I'll try to get one  that is the same cat cable as the one used with the PL adapters

Comment: @BingBong In a perfect world, you'd test with cat 5e or cat 6 cables, but for this test, almost any cable should do. We're just trying to eliminate the PL stuff.

Comment: @BingBong Status please...

Comment: Sorry, I got busy with something else. I'll try to do this tomorrow morning and report back.

Comment: Well instead of running an ethernet cord, I simply used my wifi card (I use a powerline because of lower latency). And so far (10 min in) it seems to be fine. But the issue was rather random when I was using the PL adapter so time will tell.

Comment: @BingBong Running ok off of wifi may be fine, but it doesn't tell us about what's happening with the ethernet connection. We still need to eliminate a PL issue vs something else.

Comment: Okay. Ran the ethernet cord and I'll see how that works. Again, will take about an hour to be able to tell for sure.

Comment: @BingBong Status please...

Comment: So far so good. Might just be the PL adapter then. I guess I can mark this as solved for now as that seems to be the issue. Thanks for all of your help.

Not sure how to mark this as answered. Can you write an answer response so I can give you the credit/points?

Comment: @BingBong I'm glad it appears to be working better! I've updated my answer. To accept it, just click the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with different computers (a Desktop and a Notebook), different PowerLine Ethernet adapters (Netgear and Denovo), different Ethernet Cards (RealTeck and ASIX Electronics), different cables (new cables) and different rooms (the same house).

The unique equal variable is Ubuntu 18.04.

I have more of the same PowerLine adapters connected to other devices (PS4, WiFI Router and a Win PC) and all works fine (I'm currently using 4 Denovo duo 550 CPL adapters).

I'm currently solving my issue with the following solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/1228073/1060836n can you take a look?

Comment: I've actually switched to manjaro. Sorry. Using the PL adapter and it seems fine so far, but I haven't been using my pc as much lately since the weather has gotten nicer. Your proposed solution is for forcing wifi though, I'm not using wifi....

Comment: My current solution works on the current active connection.Wifi, if you are using wifi, ethernet, if you are using ethernet. The wifi-on file name used, is arbitrary.

Comment: Will that solution work for manjaro too?

Comment: if the `/etc/cron.d/` directory is presents, I think yes. Anyway you can simple create a ctontab job.

Comment: well my internet via powerline on manjaro just crapped out. So I will try that bash script and report back in the future if I remember.

Comment: On my Ubuntu, I definitely resolved with this script. Let me updated.

Comment: internet dropped again. guess i'll try sticking with wifi for now and see if that works

Comment: are you sure that the script is currently called from the cron service? Try to simple open a terminal window and write the following command: `ping resolver1.opendns.com` leaving the terminal window open. This will be enough to solve your issue.

Comment: Ran that for 3 minutes and it never stalled out. So I guess your solution is not the answer to my problem? Not sure....next time it fails, is there a log I can pull from somewhere that would should the failure mode?

Comment: The `ping resolver1.opendns.com` command ONLY assures you that your network (independently if Ethernet or WiFi) will be always ON (without entering in PowerSave mode).
This trick solves our issue (your and mine) but is only a workaround.
I think it is an Ethernet related bug, but (at least for me) activating this simple command (running in the background forever) definitively solved the problem, and I'm currently using Ethernet for many days.
Test with this simple command. If it definitively solves your issue, I'll help you to automatize it, ok? :)