# How do I stop my computer form disconnecting from my WiFi adapter?

Tags: wireless, internet, connection

So I'm pretty new to Linux and just installed Ubuntu a few days ago and a problem I've been having with my computer is that my Wifi adapter keeps on disconnecting itself after roughly an hour of use. Do any of you people know how to stop this form happening? Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem may be related more to an excessive distance from the WiFi router than to real issues with Ubuntu.

Anyway, you could try to "force" your WiFi line in a constantly active state with this simple command:

```
sudo nano /etc/cron.d/wifi-on
```

adding as file text the following one:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO = ""

* * * * * root ping resolver1.opendns.com -w60 >/dev/null;
```

This procedure will force your WiFi to run a Ping to the OpenDns server every second, maintain your line in constant activity.

If this will not work, you can undo all this work with this simple command:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/cron.d/wifi-on
```

PS: It is more a workaround than a definitive solution, but I think it's still worth trying.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm going to move my workplace and use these commands, this is very helpful!